# C: shell pipelining confusion

Tags: c, shell, pipeline

I understand that the pipe() function gives back two file descriptors that are inherited by the child process when you call fork().

I also understand how to map file descriptors to standard in and standard out using dup2().

However, I get confused when I put it all together for piping. For example, when a process like "cat" is given, the process then forks into a parent and child, with the child writing to the parent's standard in, so that the next process can read from the standard in, right? (Unless there is no next process, in which case it just writes to standard out?)

However, isn't it an error to write to standard in? How does the next process get the previous process's output then if it reads from standard in? (Say, if we had cat | cat).

Answer (score 1):

The `pipe` function results in two file descriptors: one to write into, one to read from. It would be an error for the child to write into the reading end, but it's not an error for the child to write into the writing end and the parent to map the reading end to standard input.

Answer (score 1):

It's not wring to the standard input of itself, it's writing to the standard output of itself, which is connected to the other process's standard input by the pipe. For instance, `cat | cat` looks like this:

```
stdin -> cat -> stdout  ------ stdin -> cat -> stdout
                           ^
                           |
                         pipe
```

Answer (score 1):

When you execute

```
command1 | command2
```

the shell creates a pipe. It forks a child to run `command1`, and redirects its `stdout` to `pipe[1]`. It forks another child to run `command2`, and redirects its stdin to `pipe[0]`.  Then when `command1` writes to its `stdout`, `command2` reads it on its `stdin`.

Comment: What if it was a pipe with an arbitrary number of commands? If I loop through the commands, and there is a next command, would it suffice to just redirect the process's input to pipe[0], and if there is no next command, to redirect the process's output to pipe[1]?